# Cannot pass NSString to DetailViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

**MasterViewController.h**

```
NSString *quality;
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
#import DetailViewController.h

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    quality = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string to pass"];

    ...

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailView = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        theList = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        detailView.theList = theList;

        detailView.streamQuality = quality;

    }
}
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic ,retain) NSString *streamQuality;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
@synthesize streamQuality;

NSLog(@"Final: %@", streamQuality);
```

Output: Most I get "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x10)" 
or something random like 
"Final: Copy Audio Address"

**However this works fine:**

```
detailView.streamQuality = @"hello";
```

Comment: what is quality ? have you checked its value before passing it ot detailViewController ?

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not then stringWithFormat returns autoreleased string, so you need to retain it. Try using: quality = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"string to pass"] retain];.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a property to retain `NSString` Object **quality**.
For Eg :

```
@property (nonatomic ,copy) NSString *quality;
```

and of course you have to synthesize it :

```
@synthesize quality;
```

and then you should use this property to set the string. Like this :

```
self.quality = @"string to pass";
```

Comment: same problem again...

Comment: @Lorenz : On which line, you are getting crash ?

Comment: 0x1f7dd85:  movl   16(%edx), %edx - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x10)

Comment: @Lorenz : Have you checked using Break Points ? On which line (from the lines you added in your Question), you are getting crash ?

Comment: From this: detailView.streamQuality = quality;

Comment: detailView.streamQuality = @"hello"; works

Comment: @Lorenz : Try : `quality = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"string to pass"];`

Comment: Why Downvote ? At least explain the reason behind the downvote...

Comment: What's the point of creating a string from a literal that has no format? Just use the literal.

Comment: @Abizern : In case if OP wants to use literal with format then he/she has to use "alloc/init" or "retain" the string anyway to eliminate `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. That's all my Answer is about.

Comment: In which case the correct answer is more like `self.quality = @"some string";` which uses the memory management semantics of the property.

Comment: @Abizern : Yes, you are right. I edited my Answer now. Is that fine ?

Comment: Almost - you should be using `copy` for classes that are part of a mutable/immutable class cluster.

Comment: @Abizern : Oh, ya. Thanks for correcting me and `copy`.